# Trying to make sense of a reported leak in instruments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Instruments reports I have a memory leak with the first line of the code. But as you can see at the bottom of the code I release the flipcoin object. I have no other alloc on that line so I don't understand what could be the problem? I'm guessing there is a part of memory management that I have misunderstood, can somebody give me a hint as to what can be causeing this reported leak?

```
flipCoin= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0000.png"]];
CGRect frameX;
UIImageView *coinFlipImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage 
    imageNamed:@"0000.png"]];
frameX = coinFlipImage.frame;
frameX.origin.x = (480/2) - (frameX.size.width/2);
frameX.origin.y = (320/2) - (frameX.size.height/2);

[flipCoin initWithFrame:frameX];
flipCoin.animationImages = myImages;
flipCoin.animationDuration = 1.4; // seconds
flipCoin.animationRepeatCount = 1; // 0 = loops forever
//[flipCoin startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: flipCoin];
[coinFlipImage release];
[flipCoin release];
```

Many Thanks
-Code

Comment: Is `flipCoin` an ivar or a local var?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing an init on flipCoin twice.

Once here:

```
flipCoin= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0000.png"]];
```

And then here:

```
[flipCoin initWithFrame:frameX];
```

Instead of that second instance just set the frame like so:

```
flipCoin.frame = frameX;
```

Comment: Furthermore, you should *never* call an `init` method twice on the same instance of an object (the same `init` method or different `init` methods as is the case here).

Answer (score 2):

If you replace

```
[flipCoin initWithFrame:frameX];
```

with

```
[flipCoin setFrame:frameX];
```

does it solve the problem ?